# Problem with sort-arrow handling in TListView

Tags: listview, delphi, winapi, delphi-11-alexandria

In a 32-bit VCL Application in Windows 10 in Delphi 11 Alexandria, I have a `TListView` with two columns, client-aligned to the form. I am using this code to handle the sort-arrows in the ListView Header:

```
procedure TformMain.ListView1ColumnClick(Sender: TObject; Column: TListColumn);
begin
  FSortedColumn := Column.Index; 
  case FSortedColumn of
    0: FColumn0SortedUp := not FColumn0SortedUp;
    1: FColumn1SortedUp := not FColumn1SortedUp;
  end;
  SetListHeaderSortArrow(FSortedColumn);
end;

procedure TformMain.SetListHeaderSortArrow(const aColumnIndex: Integer);
begin
  var Header: HWND;
  var Item: Winapi.CommCtrl.THDItem;
  case aColumnIndex of
    0:
      begin
        Header := Winapi.CommCtrl.ListView_GetHeader(ListView1.Handle);
        Winapi.Windows.ZeroMemory(@Item, SizeOf(Item));
        Item.Mask := Winapi.CommCtrl.HDI_FORMAT;
        Winapi.CommCtrl.Header_GetItem(Header, 0, Item);
        Item.fmt := Item.fmt and not (HDF_SORTUP or HDF_SORTDOWN); // remove both flags

        if FColumn0SortedUp then
          Item.fmt := Item.fmt or HDF_SORTUP // include the sort ascending flag
        else
          Item.fmt := Item.fmt or HDF_SORTDOWN; // include the sort descending flag

        Header_SetItem(Header, 0, Item);
      end;
    1:
      begin
        Header := Winapi.CommCtrl.ListView_GetHeader(ListView1.Handle);
        Winapi.Windows.ZeroMemory(@Item, SizeOf(Item));
        Item.Mask := Winapi.CommCtrl.HDI_FORMAT;
        Winapi.CommCtrl.Header_GetItem(Header, 1, Item);
        Item.fmt := Item.fmt and not (HDF_SORTUP or HDF_SORTDOWN); // remove both flags

        if FColumn1SortedUp then
          Item.fmt := Item.fmt or HDF_SORTUP // include the sort ascending flag
        else
          Item.fmt := Item.fmt or HDF_SORTDOWN; // include the sort descending flag

        Header_SetItem(Header, 1, Item);
      end;
  end;
end;

procedure TformMain.ListView1Resize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // This gets inexplicably automatically executed 3 times at program start!!
  // This must be in OnResize, otherwise the sort-arrows get hidden when resizing the ListView:
  SetListHeaderSortArrow(FSortedColumn);
end;
```

When I click the column header of the SECOND column, the sort arrow on the second column appears, but the sort arrow on the first column does not disappear! Only when I resize the ListView (by resizing the form), the sort arrow on the first column disappears.
So how can I make the sort arrow on the first column immediately disappear when clicking the second column header?

Comment: When changing the flags, you are not removing the flags from the previous selected column before adding the flags to the new column.

Comment: @RemyLebeau But isn't this done automatically when I resize the ListView? The only problem is that this doesn't happen immediately when clicking the second column.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've tried removing the flags from the previous column. But that doesn't work. The arrow is removed from the previous column only when resizing the ListView.

Comment: Clicking a header doesn't resize the ListView. And in any case, there shouldnt be any need to reset flags on a resize anyway. You need to remove the flags explicitly from the old column, but you are not doing that.

Comment: "Clicking a header doesn't resize the ListView." I never claimed that. Have you tried the code yourself?

Comment: I have found a workaround by doing this at the end of `OnColumnClick`: `Self.Width := Self.Width + 1; Self.Width := Self.Width - 1;` It works. But I don't know why it works.

Comment: "*Have you tried the code yourself?*" - yes, I have, which is how I know it works as I have described. And there are [numerous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelphi*%5D+HDF_SORTUP) on StackOverflow on this very topic, several of which I have posted answers to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When changing the flags, you are not removing the flags from the previous selected column before adding the flags to the new column.

Try something more like this instead:

```pascal
private:
  FColumnSortedUp: array[0..1] of Boolean;
  FSortedColumn: Integer;

...

procedure TformMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FSortedColumn := -1;
end;

procedure TformMain.ListView1ColumnClick(Sender: TObject; Column: TListColumn);
begin
  if FSortedColumn <> -1 then
    SetListHeaderSortArrow(FSortedColumn, False);

  if FSortedColumn = Column.Index then
    FColumnSortedUp[FSortedColumn] := not FColumnSortedUp[FSortedColumn];
  else
    FSortedColumn := Column.Index;

  SetListHeaderSortArrow(FSortedColumn, True);

  // sort ListView items as needed...
end;

procedure TformMain.SetListHeaderSortArrow(const aColumnIndex: Integer;
  const aEnabled: Boolean);
var
  Header: HWND;
  Item: THDItem;
begin
  Header := ListView_GetHeader(ListView1.Handle);
  ZeroMemory(@Item, SizeOf(Item));
  Item.Mask := HDI_FORMAT;
  Header_GetItem(Header, aColumnIndex, Item);
  Item.fmt := Item.fmt and not (HDF_SORTUP or HDF_SORTDOWN); // remove both flags

  if aEnabled then
  begin
    if FColumnSortedUp[aColumnIndex] then
      Item.fmt := Item.fmt or HDF_SORTUP // include the sort ascending flag
    else
      Item.fmt := Item.fmt or HDF_SORTDOWN; // include the sort descending flag
  end;

  Header_SetItem(Header, aColumnIndex, Item);
end;
```

Also note that the sort arrow does not disappear when the *ListView* is resized, but when the *column* is resized.  So you will have to hook the ListView to handle `HDN_ENDTRACK` notifications to detect when each column is resized, eg:

```pascal
private
  ...
  OldWndProc: TWndMethod;
  procedure ListViewWndProc(var Message: TMessage);

...

uses
  ..., Winapi.Messages, Winapi.CommCtrl;

procedure TformMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ...
  OldWndProc := ListView1.WindowProc;
  ListView1.WindowProc := ListViewWndProc;
end;

procedure TformMain.ListViewWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  OldWndProc(Message);
  if Message.Msg = WM_NOTIFY then
  begin
    if TWMNotify(Message).NMHdr.code = HDN_ENDTRACK then
    begin
      if PHDNotify(TWMNotify(Message).NMHdr).Item = FSortedColumn then
        SetListHeaderSortArrow(FSortedColumn, True);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: There is a typo in your code: `procedure TformMain.ListViewWndProc(var Message: TMessage);` instead of `ListViewWndProc.ListViewWndProc`. However, the main problem still persists: When resizing the window the sort-arrow still DISAPPEARS!

Comment: However, the problem is solved when in ListView1Resize I execute this code: `if FSortedColumn <> -1 then
    SetListHeaderSortArrow(FSortedColumn, True);`

Comment: @user1580348 I tested the code on multiple machines and different OS versions before posting it here. The arrow disappears for me only when the column is resized, not when the whole ListView is resized. Adding the `HDN_ENDTRACK` handler fixes that for me.

Comment: Have you considered that `ListView1.Align = alClient`?

Comment: @user1580348 Yes, in fact my test used exacty that.

Comment: "// sort ListView items as needed...: (Sender as TCustomListView).AlphaSort"
In the ListView's `Compare` handler `Caption` is UNDECLARED: https://i.imgur.com/XENDSRV.png

Comment: @user1580348 that screenshot is also complaining about `SubItems`, too. This would imply that `Item1` and `Item2` are not declared as `Vcl.ComCtrls.TListItem`. But this is completely separate from the issue of handling sort arrows on the ListView columns. So if you are having troubles with your `OnCompare` handler, that warrants posting a separate question about it.

Comment: This is a TYPE AMBIGUITY error (with `TMS WEB Core RSXE14\Component Library Source\WEBLib.Lists.pas`): Redeclaring the `TListitem` parameter as `Vcl.ComCtrls.TListItem` solved the problem.

Comment: After inspecting my `interface uses` clause, I discovered that some "unknown ghost" must have inserted `WEBLib.Lists` there.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround that solves the problem:

```
procedure PALockWinControl(const WC: Vcl.Controls.TWinControl; ALock: Boolean);
begin
  if (not Assigned(WC)) or (WC.Handle = 0) then EXIT;

  if ALock then
    WC.Perform(WM_SETREDRAW, 0, 0)
  else
  begin
    WC.Perform(WM_SETREDRAW, 1, 0);
    RedrawWindow(WC.Handle, nil, 0, RDW_ERASE or RDW_FRAME or RDW_INVALIDATE or RDW_ALLCHILDREN);
  end;
end;

procedure MyRedrawWorkaround;
begin
  with formMain do
  begin
    PALockWinControl(ListView1, True);
    try
      ListView1.Align := alNone;
      ListView1.Width := lvMRUProjects.Width - 1;
      ListView1.Align := alClient;
    finally
      PALockWinControl(ListView1, False);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TformMain.ListView1ColumnClick(Sender: TObject; Column: TListColumn);
begin
  FSortedColumn := Column.Index;
  case FSortedColumn of
    0: FColumn0SortedUp := not FColumn0SortedUp;
    1: FColumn1SortedUp := not FColumn1SortedUp;
  end;
  SetListHeaderSortArrow(FSortedColumn);

  MyRedrawWorkaround;
end;
```

Comment: This workaround is completely unnecessary.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70597160/65863).